# SAS creating data sets in the /home directory

Tags: unix, sas

Is there any process by which SAS creates data sets(.sas7bdat extension) in the /home directory? we have both 9.3 and 9.4 installed on the unix server.
The programmers do not have access to the /home directory but there are some files which are being generated at this location without the knowledge of programmers.
Please Help.

Comment: What are some filenames that are being created? Maybe that will give a clue?

Comment: Files of extension .sas7bdat and .log are getting generated.

Answer (score 1):

This is the default output location for any shell commands run by those users on the server. All sorts of things will typically end up there if they mistype the occasional command. One way to change this so that SAS outputs these sorts of files to the work library instead is to run the following in a session on the server:

```
x "cd %sysfunc(pathname(work))";
```

E.g. suppose you have a command like this:

```
echo Hello > myfile.txt
```

Unless you run a `cd` command first, `myfile.txt` will be created in your home directory by default.

Comment: could you please explain what you meant by the line 
 "All sorts of things will typically end up there if they mistype the occasional command."
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your input :)